# Landscape Autopilot Installer juju ended with exit code 1

Tags: networking, maas, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I'm trying to install an Autopilot Landscape based cloud. I go past the steps selecting the services and then the hardware. The next step is the deployment, where it begins by running juju bootstrap on the first node. The node says "deployed" in MAAS but the Landscape installer gets stuck.

Here is the error:

```
    juju ended with exit code 1 (out='', err='Bootstrapping environment "1"
Starting new instance for initial state server
Launching instance
 - /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-f86836fa-4d60-11e6-b0a6-002590c3a86e/
Installing Juju agent on bootstrap instance
Waiting for address
Attempting to connect to IX2-M09-28.maas:22
Attempting to connect to IX2-M09-28.maas:22
Attempting to connect to 10.1.3.101:22
Attempting to connect to 104.254.214.3:22
```

here is the full error:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/20022764/

here is my ifconfig

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1548320 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1548320 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:577618249 (577.6 MB)  TX bytes:577618249 (577.6 MB)

lxcbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b6:46:f7:24:9d:1a
          inet addr:10.0.3.1  Bcast:10.0.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::b446:f7ff:fe24:9d1a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:648 (648.0 B)

p2p1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:c3:a8:6e
          inet addr:104.2XX.XXX.2  Bcast:104.2XX.XXX.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:fec3:a86e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:728835 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1137937 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:449391074 (449.3 MB)  TX bytes:1526276817 (1.5 GB)
          Memory:fb980000-fba00000

p2p2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:c3:a8:6f
          inet addr:10.1.3.2  Bcast:10.1.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:fec3:a86f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1142988 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2141794 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:79832182 (79.8 MB)  TX bytes:3182895176 (3.1 GB)
          Memory:fb900000-fb980000

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a2:3f:3a:3e:c3:45
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I have all nodes with 2 NICs. 1 NIC for the Public network and one NIC for the Private network. I am able to boot and deploy nodes from the private network "p2p2".

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto p2p1
iface p2p1 inet static
        address 104.2XX.XXX.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 104.2XX.XXX.0
        broadcast 104.2XX.XXX.255
        gateway 104.2XX.XXX.1
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 4.2.2.2 8.8.4.4



#secondary network interface - private
auto p2p2
iface p2p2 inet static
        address 10.1.3.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 10.1.3.0
        broadcast 10.1.3.255
```

How can I achieve this network topology? Do I need to start over? I must be missing something. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Can you please provide also your hardware details and other relevant pieces of information at the end of your body.

Answer (score 0):

The logs show that the MAAS machine that Autopilot picked to bootstrap on doesn't have access to streams.canonical.com, can you confirm if you have a firewall in place?